# Which NumberStyles to use in order to have the right number conversion?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, double, precision, regional-settings

I'm reading value from an excel sheet.
The correct value of the cell is  -0.09   but excel reads it as  "-9.3299999999999994E-2"
I created a method handling regional setting (comma and period in number format)to convert value correctly   and to handle Excel misunderstanding .

Every thing works fine till the last instruction where I do the conversion via the NumberStyles
the result of the last instruction is -933 instead of -0.09

What is the change I need to do in order to have the right answer ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String data = "-9.3299999999999994E-2";
        double number = 0.0;

        string s = Regex.Replace(data, @"\s", "");

        //Handle scientif Notation Coming from Excel e.g: 1.234567E-06
        if (s.ToUpper().Contains("E"))
        {
            try
            {
                number = double.Parse(s.Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                s = number.ToString();
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                throw new FormatException();
            }
        }
        var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        // if the first regex matches, the number string is in us culture
        if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(:?[\d,]+\.)*\d+$"))
        {
            cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        }
        // if the second regex matches, the number string is in de culture
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(:?[\d.]+,)*\d+$"))
        {
            cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        }
        NumberStyles styles = NumberStyles.Number ;

        bool isDouble = double.TryParse(s.Trim(),styles, cultureInfo, out number);
        if (!isDouble) //if conversion fails            
            throw new FormatException();

        System.Console.WriteLine ( number );
}
```

Comment: Why are you retrieving values from Excel as a `string`? Are you reading a CSV file? Why are you doing multiple parse conversions (e.g. for scientific notation)?

Comment: I am trying to handle every Regional Setting In case the user is working with a machine with American Regional Setting or other. So I do more than one attempts to convert

Comment: But you process Scientific Notation more than once - that makes no sense (e.g. you re-assign `s`).